# My newly updated Droid rings at max volume even when ringtone is muted

Tags: updates, samsung-galaxy-j7

I was forced to install a mandatory update (Droid version 9, Kernel version 3.18.91-16068741) for my Samsung Galaxy J7 around 2 weeks ago. Since then, there have been six (6) incidents where my phone rings EVEN IF MY RINGTONE IS SET TO MUTE. Is this a bug with the new update or did the change break a setting? As a last resort, how do I downgrade?

Comment: Does it always happens or from time to time?

Comment: It seems to happen randomly.

Comment: If you were updating from android 8 to 9 than in that case factory reset might be a good option, anyway in case of any update it might be a good to do a factory reset if it causes any problems.

Comment: Ugh...Did a factory reset yesterday and it just went off now. That didn't work :(

Comment: Did you restore a backup? Does the issue happen with a selected caller? Might be a case of some whitelisted contact that should be allowed to bypass silent mode?

Comment: Its most likely a bug, or an app overriding the volume, which can be changed in the apps settings. And if you want to downgrade, you will have to flash the os through *adb* with root permissions

Comment: @Rac3rZer0 `flash the os through adb with root permissions` - sorry but are you sure? I have never seen a device you could be flashed via adb. Usually this works totally different (fastboot, odin, mtk flash tools, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using do not disturb, that usually helps by going to **Settings > Sounds and notifications** and check that the following are selected to how you want. There are two options:

- Volume: To adjust the volume level for music and videos,  system sounds, call ringtones, and notifications.
- Do not disturb: **Mute incoming call and notification sounds**, except for **allowed exceptions.**

> For the **Do not Disturb** option, check that you are not leaving an exception for incoming calls before enabling because that could be one of the problems too.

Also, as a last resort like you said, you can also flash your phone using this well-explained guide by clicking the link [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-j7-2017/development/rom-stock-rom-7-0-1-flash-repair-t3766193) (don't mind the title, the process of flashing can either upgrade(which you don't want) or downgrade(which, of course, you want) ) which will provide all the resources you need to properly flash your phone.

> **REMEMBER:** I am **not** responsible if you brick your phone if you follow these instructions incorrectly. **MAKE SURE** you select your correct device along with the correct ROM you want to use on the [SamMobile](http://sammobile.com/firmwares/) website, meaning, since you want to downgrade, select a firmware other than the 9.0 Pie firmware, so an older one like one back in 2017. If you don't know how to use Odin, follow [this link](https://samsungodin.com/how-to-use-odin/) which will provide you with instructions of how to use it. 
> **ALSO NOTE:** To avoid the stress of you permanently bricking your phone, install a custom recovery like [TWRP](https://twrp.me/Devices/), which will make life easier when you have to deal with a bricked phone.

I  hope these instructions were helpful and wish you the best of luck.

Cheers, 
Joe